# System Monitor vs Operating System

Tags: operating-systems

I'm having a tough time finding the distinction between the two.
My understanding is that "operating system" refers to a more abstracted job monitor with extended functionality (e.g. task-scheduling, virtual memory allocation, etc).
Is that really the case, or am I missing a more substantial difference?

Comment: Terms like "system monitor" or "operating system" are only rough categories for software, not protected brands - any software vendor or author can use them the way they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody would refer to Windows as a "system monitor".

In fact, very few people would use the term "system monitor" these days to refer to software with the management role. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) uses it to refer to an *informational* role. That is, a system monitor is a tool for getting monitoring information out of the operating system and presenting it to the user or system administrator.